# Get the distinct rows with oldest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
MyTable:
   id: pk
   numero: varchar
   data_modif: timestamp
   ...
```

I have multiple records with same value in `numero` and I need to return each distinct `numero` record with oldest `data_modif`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like aggregation:

```
select numero, min(data_modif)
from mytable
group by numero;
```

If you want the entire row, then window functions are one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by numero order by data_modif asc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

In an old version of MySQL, you woudl use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.data_modif = (select min(t2.data_modif)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.numero = t.numero
                     );
```

Comment: Yes, I want the full row, should have described that. Your second answer should be my way to go but I'm getting an error saying `Select is not valid in this position for this server version`, I looked it up thinking my version didn't support window functions but it does (it's myql 14.14 FYI). It's there a way to do the same behaviour with  logic in the select clause not in from?